# How to call a macro inside a macro?

Tags: c, macros

is it possible to call macro inside a macro in this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define AA(a1, a2) a1, 3, 5, a2
#define BB(x, y1, y2, y3, y4) { printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n",x, y1, y2, y3, y4 ); }

int main ()
{
   int n = 21, k= 11;
   BB(31, AA(n,k));
}
```

this code returns the followinf error in the compilation:

> test_macro.c: In function ‘main’:
>   test_macro.c:9:18: erreur: macro « BB » requiert 5 arguments, mais seulement 2 ont été passés
>   test_macro.c:9:4: erreur: ‘BB’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>   test_macro.c:9:4: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

Comment: are you really missing the ending `}`?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Omit the semicolon after the macro, or - better - if using gcc, parenthesise the whole macro body (non-standard) to make that an expression.

Comment: The problem is in your error.  You've defined BB with 5 parameters, and only supplied 2 when you call it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you probably want is to supply additional arguments of `BB` by expansion of `AA(n,k)`. As pointed by Sourav Ghosh, in your program, `AA(n,k)` is expanded after being passed to `BB` as a single argument. To get it expanded before, you can use one more macro level and define your program as:

```
#define AA(a1, a2) a1, 3, 5, a2
#define BB(x, y1, y2, y3, y4) { printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n",x, y1, y2, y3, y4 ); }
#define BBB(a,b) BB(a,b)

int main ()
{
  int n = 21, k= 11;
  BBB(31, AA(n,k));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In your code, when the following line is encountered, in preprocessing stage,

```
BB(31, AA(n,k));
```

as per the rule of MACRO substitution, first, `BB` will get expanded (replaced) as specified in the *replacement-list*, then, in the replacement list, if any other MACRO substitution is possible (here, `AA`), that will take place next.

There the problem arises. MACRO definition of `BB` takes 5 arguments, but you're passing only 2, because, the expansion of `AA` did not take place yet.

Related, from `C11`, chapter §6.10.3, Macro replacement (*emphasis mine*)

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> ```
>   # define identifier replacement-list new-line
> ```
>
> defines an object-like macro that causes each subsequent instance of the macro name to be replaced by the replacement list of preprocessing tokens that constitute the remainder of the directive. **The replacement list is then rescanned for more macro names as specified below.**